# Jersey Exception Mapping Different Context

Tags: java, model-view-controller, exception, jersey

So I am build an mvc application using Jersey. A method that accepts Path parameters (@PathParam).

If a custom exception is thrown (ExampleException) then a 404 Not Found response is returned using an exception mapper.

```
@Provider
public class ExampleExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ExampleException>  {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ExampleException ex) {
        return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Not Found - " + ex.getMessage()).build();
    }

}
```

However, I am implementing @FormParam's so a user POSTs to the server. The same exact exception is raised, but instead I should return a 400 Bad Request response. Without modifying the exception how would I be able to make the exception mapper return the proper response code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is create multiple ExceptionMappers, each for specific subclass of ExampleException.

But you want to have the same exception for both cases and decide whether to throw 404 for GET/PathParam and POST/FormParam, you can inject the [request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Request.html) into the mapper and check what method it is:

```
@Provider
public class ExampleExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ExampleException>  {
    @Context Request request;         
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ExampleException ex) {
        if ("POST".equals(requset.getMethod()))
           return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        else
           return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Not Found - " +    ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```

If you want to decide by PathParams, you can inject [UriInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/UriInfo.html):

```
@Provider
public class ExampleExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ExampleException>  {
    @Context UriInfo info;         
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ExampleException ex) {
        if (info.getPathParameters().isEmpty())) //please make better condition based on your needs
           return Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).build();
        else
           return Response.status(Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Not Found - " +    ex.getMessage()).build();
    }
}
```